# Why is my hard drive not found in boot priority order? ”No bootable device found”

Tags: hard-drive, boot

My hard drive is not found in boot priority order.

When I open the laptop it gives me an error “no bootable device found.”

My hard drive is enabled in drive configurations screen inside my Phoenix SecureCore Tiano setup but not shown in boot order.

If I try to install a new Windows with USB flash drive would the problem be solved and the hard drive will be shown on priority boot order?

[image]

Comment: You can indeed install Windows from USB, but you should verify afterward the disk's SMART attributes. A catastrophic error like this may indicate hardware problems.

Comment: On installing windows would the hard drive partitions be visible for installing windows and it becomes visible in the boot priority order again  ?

Comment: If the installation can't see the disk, then it likely in a bad shape.

Comment: I will try and reach back to you

Comment: I installed a new windows and the hard drive partitions showed up , everything was cool but still my ssd hard drive not detected in the boot priority order in bios , just the windows boot manager

Comment: I checked the disk SMART attributes and the status was ok.

Comment: The BIOS will only list disks with boot code. If you have another SSD, check to see if the installation can see it (not the BIOS).

Comment: I checked the boot priority order now & ssd hard drive is now detected after i checked the smart attributes and the status was ok i head to the boot priority order and the hard becomes visible

Comment: Does that mean that the problem is resolved?

Comment: Yeah the problem is solved, thank you so much

Comment: Can you convert your comment to an answer so that i can mark it as a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hard disk was not shown in the boot menu, since the menu will
only list disks or partitions that contain boot code.

This means that Windows has to be installed before the disk becomes
a candidate for the boot menu.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling should indeed fix the registration of your Windows installation, but normally your hard disk should show up in the boot menu so I don't think the problem is the registration of Windows but the hard drive might not be seen by your hardware. You can check if you unplug your hard drive if any items from the boot order disappear, and if plugging the disk back in and rebooting again makes it show up. If not, check if the Windows PE environment can find your hard drive. I don't think USB HDD is the hard drive but you never know.

Does the disk make noise when powered on? Can you read the disk from another computer? You can trouble shoot with this to see if the disk is at fault or the computer.

Comment: I installed a new windows and the hard drive partitions showed up and windows was active successfully, everything was cool but still my ssd hard drive not detected in the boot priority order in bios , just the windows boot manager

Comment: I checked the disk SMART attributes and the status was ok